# CefSharp embedded browser on .net not rendering Google StreetView

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, cefsharp, google-street-view

I have a Vb.Net WinForm Application with Cef Browser embedded onto this.
I use this browser to see Google Maps and Google Street View in the same app.
Use the Cef Browser because the embedded IE Browser gives me headache with the compatibility with the Google Maps JS API.
On almost all of the computers where the app is running, is running fine.
The problem is with one specific computer that can't render the Google Street View (Google Maps renders OK).
And it works on a normal browser like Google Chrome.

Here a Screenshot.
[image: Poorly rendered Google StreetView on CefSharp Browser]

It's like it load only one picture, but when i move the camera it unload the picture and load another picture in the same place. Always one picture at the time. So weird.

I have no idea where to look for a solution.

Comment: Open devtools and check the log file, by default debug.log is created in your executing folder. Make sure you have the latest graphics drivers installed.

Comment: It works on a normal browser like Google Chrome. It's in the CefSharp Browser, do you think it could be the drivers? I will check the folder to see if there is anything on the file you mentioned.

Comment: To be blunt and I hope you take this in a constructive way, the details you've provided are pretty much useless. You say it works on some computers and not another. Where is your analysis of the situation? What hardware and operating system combinations does it work on? How does that compare? You may need to compare them at a deeper level if nothing stands out, driver versions, .net versions. You say it works in chrome, are you comparing the same version? The details about having problems with the default IE control are useless. Make sense?